# High charts draggable not working for log scale

Tags: logging, highcharts, draggable

We are using high charts draggable code in: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/

```
var colProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype,
baseDrawTracker = colProto.drawTracker;

colProto.drawTracker = function () {
    var series = this;
    baseDrawTracker.apply(series);
    each(series.points, function (point) {
        point.graphic.attr(point.shapeArgs.height < 3 ? {
            'stroke': 'black',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'dashstyle': 'shortdot'
        } : {
            'stroke-width': series.options.borderWidth,
            'dashstyle': series.options.dashStyle || 'solid'
        });
    });
};
```

Where drag-drop events in the highcharts are implemented.

For implementing draggable functionality to the column chart its working fine for normal chart scale. Now we have a requirement to represent very small values and very high values in the same chart by relative representation of individual column. So I changed the highcharts scale to 'logarithmic' (In the process I eliminated 0 values since log 0 = infinite). Now the chart is getting rendered but the drag functionality stopped working.

I am getting the following error in console:

> point.graphic is undefined.

Please help me out if anyone has some idea on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with your code that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/846/

There is only one limitation as I can see: `stacking: 'normal'` doesn't work for drag module.

Comment: But in the example you have provided dragging is not optimal. I mean when start dragging a value it is not starting from its original value, instead it is going to a value some where around 2.1(shrinks) and then the column size is extending

Comment: Oh, that seems that plugin doesn't work properly. I have fixed that using translate() function with proper arguments for log axis: `yAxis.translate(newPlotY, true, false, false, true)`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/AyUbx/847/